# Access a field of a class that is somewhere else?

Tags: java, class, field

How do I access the `z` instance in a non-static method in the `Y` class?

```
class X {
    Y y = new Y();
    Z z = new Z();
    y.doSomething();
}

class Y {
    void doSomething() {
        z.foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `z` is non-static it means it doesn't belong to class, but to specific instance of that class. So you can access it only by reference holding some instance.

You can create such reference with instance in `doSomething` method, but that is rarely good idea. Usually we simply pass instance to method as its argument like

```
void doSomething(X someX){
    someX.z.foo();
}
```

and generally it is better if field is private, if you would want to access it create getter method) so now you can invoke it like `y.doSomething(x)`.

Also you can't invoke `y.doSomething(x);` on class level, you need to place it in code block like constructor, method, or initialization block.